# Login Logout Time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has Employee Id, EventDateTime and EventType.

Description of Row:

- Employee Id - Provides ID of an employee
- EventDateTime - Date and Time when the event occurs fora particular event we have id in Event Type.
- Event Type - 1 for Login, 7 - Logout.

Now I have to find out login time and logout time of the employee for particular date. Employee can login and logout multiple time in the day but i want to find login time as earliest login and logout as latest time.

This is how data looks -

```
AGENTID EVENTDATETIME           EVENTTYPE
504     04/03/2015 1:05:02 PM   1
504     04/03/2015 3:26:16 PM   7
504     04/03/2015 3:28:52 PM   1
504     04/03/2015 3:30:25 PM   7
504     04/03/2015 3:31:41 PM   1
504     04/03/2015 5:40:19 PM   7
504     04/03/2015 5:43:40 PM   1
504     04/03/2015 10:07:59 PM  7
```

I have tried following code to obtain same

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT
     [EVENTTYPE]
    ,[EVENTDATETIME]
    ,[EVENTDATE] = CAST([EVENTDATETIME] AS DATE)
    ,[LOGONUSER] = [AGENTID]
    ,[LOGOFFUSER] = LEAD([AGENTID], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [AGENTID], [EVENTDATETIME])
    ,[LOGONACTIVITYTIME] = [EVENTDATETIME]
    ,[LOGOFFACTIVITYTIME] = LAG([EVENTDATETIME], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [AGENTID], [EVENTDATETIME])
    ,[LOGONACTIVITYDATE] = CAST([EVENTDATETIME] AS DATE)
    ,[LOGOFFACTIVITYDATE] = CAST(LAG([EVENTDATETIME], 1) OVER(ORDER BY [AGENTID], [EVENTDATETIME]) AS DATE)
FROM [dbo].[tblAGENTSTATEDETAIL]
)
SELECT
     [LOGONUSER] [AGENTID]
    ,[EVENTDATETIME]
    ,[LOGONACTIVITYDATE]
    ,[LOGOFFACTIVITYDATE]
    ,([LOGONACTIVITYTIME]) AS [LOGON]
    ,([LOGOFFACTIVITYTIME]) AS [LOGOFF]
FROM CTE
WHERE [EVENTTYPE] in 1
    AND [LOGOFFACTIVITYTIME] IS NOT NULL
    AND [LOGONUSER] = [LOGOFFUSER]
    AND [LOGONACTIVITYDATE] = [LOGOFFACTIVITYDATE]
```

But it does not work they I want. here i get all the time and not the only one login and logout time.

I would really appreciate if someone could guide me with it

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take on this. You should be able to use this to wedge it into what you have. Someone might have a better solution, this one seems like overkill, but this gets what it sounds like you are describing.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (AGENTID int, EVENTDATETIME datetime, EVENTTYPE int)

INSERT INTO #temp (AGENTID, EVENTDATETIME, EVENTTYPE)
VALUES (504,'04/03/2015 1:05:02 PM',1),
(504,'04/03/2015 3:26:16 PM',7),
(504,'04/03/2015 3:28:52 PM',1),
(504,'04/03/2015 3:30:25 PM',7),
(504,'04/03/2015 3:31:41 PM',1),
(504,'04/03/2015 5:40:19 PM',7),
(504,'04/03/2015 5:43:40 PM',1),
(504,'04/03/2015 10:07:59 PM',7),

(504,'04/04/2015 3:28:52 PM',1),
(504,'04/04/2015 3:30:25 PM',7),
(504,'04/04/2015 3:31:41 PM',1),
(504,'04/04/2015 5:40:19 PM',7)

SELECT DISTINCT AGENTID, CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) AS [Date], 
MIN([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE]) AS first_login, 
MAX([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE] DESC) AS last_logout,
DATEDIFF(MI, MIN([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE]), 
MAX([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE] DESC)) AS login_mins,
DATEDIFF(MI, MIN([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE]), 
MAX([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE] DESC))/60.0 AS login_hrs
FROM #temp 


DROP TABLE #temp
```

Output:

```
AGENTID     Date       first_login             last_logout             login_mins  login_hrs
----------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------
504         2015-04-03 2015-04-03 13:05:02.000 2015-04-03 22:07:59.000 542         9.033333
504         2015-04-04 2015-04-04 15:28:52.000 2015-04-04 17:40:19.000 132         2.200000
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your solution.

But this does not give right solution. What i get is login time for same day but logout time on of some other day.

Comment: @AbdulquadirShaikh, I have updated the solution with a new query.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this helps a bit.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this helps a bit.

But if you could help with in some cases it is possible that agent as not logout on and I want to say logout date time as null so can you tell me how can i handle that.

And Same can be possible with Login Time

Thanks in advance

Comment: That is a new question.

Comment: No I want to incorporate that in the same query.

Comment: I understand that. But that is stretching the scope away from the original question. Put in a new question with those requirements. Otherwise, where does this one end?

Comment: Ok I would do that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably intended to use [FIRST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx) and [LAST_VALUE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx) instead of [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) and [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx).

Assuming you've already narrowed to a single day and a single AGENTID, this would look like:

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(EVENTDATETIME) OVER(ORDER BY EVENTDATETIME) AS FIRST_LOGIN WHERE EVENTTYPE = 1

SELECT LAST_VALUE(EVENTDATETIME) OVER(ORDER BY EVENTDATETIME) AS LAST_LOGOUT WHERE EVENTTYPE = 7
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Also can you tell me are you suggesting to create two different tables for login and logout. And if not how would I corporate above logic in the code that I shared.

Comment: There are several ways to get data into intermediate forms, such as creating a #temp table, using a cursor, or using a CTE as you have done.  That part is up to you.  I am hoping to help with a possible misunderstanding about LEAD and LAG, which (when used with 1 as an argument) give you the immediately following/preceding record.  It seems that isn't what you are trying to do in this case.