# Filter Column with separate condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find login and logout time from a table. I am able to figure out login and logout time.

You can see below link for that. [Login Logout Time in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42655443/login-logout-time-in-sql-server)

The solution for this is

```
    SELECT DISTINCT AGENTID, CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) AS [Date], 
MIN([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE]) AS first_login, 
MAX([EVENTDATETIME]) OVER (PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) ORDER BY [EVENTTYPE] DESC) AS last_logout,
FROM #temp
```

Now here what i suppose to do this filter column **first_login** by **EVENTTYPE = 1** and **last_logout** by **EVENTTYPE = 1**.

Can you suggest a way to do that.

Comment: If you cant filter when #temp is created you can use it in a subquery.  Replace from #temp with from (select ... From #temp Where filter...) tempfiltered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression in `MIN` and `MAX` window functions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
AGENTID, 
CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date) AS [Date], 
MIN(CASE WHEN EVENTTYPE = 1 THEN [EVENTDATETIME] END) OVER(PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date)) AS first_login, 
MAX(CASE WHEN EVENTTYPE = 1 THEN [EVENTDATETIME] END) OVER(PARTITION BY [AGENTID], CAST(EVENTDATETIME AS date)) AS last_logout
FROM #temp
```